# JavaScript Delete an element in an array of objects by property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects in the form of

```
[  
   {prop1: value1,
   banks:[{_id:value,property2:value2}]
}]
```

So what I want to do is delete an element in "banks" property by searching for the "_id" value and then remove the found element from the banks array

"_id" property has unique values so there are no multiple occurrences of any value

I am doing this like

```
$scope.account.banks.splice($scope.account.banks.indexOf(item),1);
```

is there any better way for doing this?

Comment: Does `indexOf` on `item` actually work?

Comment: Should be moved to [codereview.se]

Comment: item is an object with the all the same properties as an object in banks array would have. But, I am not getting the right results that's why I posted on SO

Comment: Your 'accounts' array isn't a valid array. Is it actually an array of objects, each with `prop1` and `banks` as members?

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot the braces while typing. I'll edit it

Comment: is this a mongodb query? If yes then the accepted answer is not the way to go.

Comment: No, it is not. I am using this on client side so it is on angularjs and not in server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the banks that match `item`. Its a little cleaner than manually looping though it's still a little verbose. I made a little test case to illustrate what I'm talking about.

```js
var accounts = [{
   prop1: 'value1',
   banks:[{_id:0,property2:'sdfbra'},
          {_id:1,property2:'qwedfg'},
          {_id:2,property2:'gaasdf'},
          {_id:3,property2:'asdfaa'}]
}]

var item = {_id:1,property2:'qwedfg'};

accounts[0].banks = accounts[0].banks.filter(function(element){
  return element._id !== item._id;
});

console.log (accounts[0].banks);
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do it would be, if possible, to turn the banks array into a Map so you don't need to loop over the array, which may not scale well:

```
var m = new Map()
for(var bank of account.banks)
  m.set(bank._id, bank)
account.banks = m
```

Then you can remove items by id directly:

```
account.banks.delete(id)
```

Or do it with a regular object even. That way it wouldn't break your Angular code:

```
var m = {}
for(var bank of account.banks)
  m[bank._id] = bank
account.banks = m
```

…

```
delete account.banks[id]
```

Comment: This is probably way more efficient. Especially if you're accessing banks by _id all the time.